# How can I listen for uninstalling an apk?

Tags: android

How can I listen for an apk being uninstalled?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) Intent and [Listening For and Broadcasting Global Messages, and Setting Alarms](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers).

Comment: Do you know if a developer can catch that Intent to avoid the user from unistalling an application ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to cancel the intent. Moreover, the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` intent is sent when the uninstall process has already finished.